# Как визуализировать углы вокруг изображения <img> средствами CSS?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, вёрстка, img

Недавно захотел обновить сайт на `WordPress`, да в `CSS` не сильно силён. Решил добавить к изображениям рамку в виде углов, но не нашёл решения, как можно это реализовать. Пробовал что-то сделать с `border`, но он обводит картинку целиком, а обводку на половину настроить как я понял, нельзя.

Есть варианты того, как это можно реализовать средствами `CSS`? Или для такого придётся использовать `JS`?

[image: Пример отображения углов]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16050006/css-border-on-corners-only

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Вот пример с linear-gradient:

```css
div {
  width: 20vw;
  height: 20vw;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
  background-image: linear-gradient(red 5vw, transparent 5vw, transparent 15vw, red 15vw), linear-gradient(90deg, red 5vw, transparent 5vw, transparent 15vw, red 15vw), linear-gradient(red 5vw, transparent 5vw, transparent 15vw, red 15vw), linear-gradient(90deg, red 5vw, transparent 5vw, transparent 15vw, red 15vw);
  background-size: 5px 20vw, 20vw 5px, 5px 20vw, 20vw 5px;
  background-position: 0 0, 0 0, 100% 100%, 100% 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat, no-repeat, no-repeat, no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: Так то оно работает, но проблема в том, что работает это практически со всем ( <div>, <p> ), но при использовании на img это всё пропадает. Возможно, я чего то недопонимаю, но вставил это вот так - http://prntscr.com/i6esir

Comment: @SharkVil, ну так, укажите класс для этого и все заработает. А так же - это можно решить через псевдоэлементы `::after` и `::before`

Answer (score -2):

Кароче, пока не нашёл варианта лучше, как поставить изображение, и подогнать его под размер фото. Однако выходит не совсем то что хотелось, но хотя бы что-то.

```css
img {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  /* Safari/Chrome, other WebKit */
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  /* Firefox, other Gecko */
  box-sizing: border-box;
  /* Opera/IE 8+ */
  border: 15px solid #000000;
  border-image: url('https://dl.dropbox.com/s/0gnnj2n8988t2lv/obvodk.png') 34% repeat;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://dl.dropbox.com/s/uxem86y8ev9jv9s/dog.jpg">
```